# To enable preview feature of azure resource provider

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to enable an azure preview feature via terraform. I have configured skip provider registration but when I tried to apply still get provider already exists error. I have to import manually as a workaround.

QUERY?:
do we must import manually to avoid provider exist error when register preview feature?
as I already define skip registration but seems it didn’t work.

Thanks!

======== configuration ========

Configure the Azure provider

```
 terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
           source =            "hashicorp/azurerm”
           version = “~> 2.99"
             }
           }

 required_version = “>= 1.1.0”
 }

 provider “azurerm” {
    features {}

skip_provider_registration =        true
```

}

```
resource        “azurerm_resource_provider_registration” “example” {
  name = “Microsoft.Network”

  feature {
    name =     “AFWEnableNetworkRuleNameLogging”
    registered = true
}
}



have configured to skip provider registration but when I tried to apply still get provider already exists.
  ======== error log 
 terraform apply main.tf plan

        azurerm_resource_provider_registration.example: Creating…
```

╷
│    Error: A resource with the ID.   “/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network” already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for “azurerm_resource_provider_registration” for more information.

Any solution on the above requirement to enable the preview feature of the corresponding namespace resource provider.

Answer (score 0):

If the Terraform statefile already contains the relevant providers, we should import it first before making any changes. Then only Terraform will read the respective changes from statefile.

**Step1:**
Add below code in provider tf and main tf as below

**provider tf file**

```
terraform {
  
      required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
           source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
           version = "~> 2.99"
             }
           }
 }

 provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

**main tf file as follows**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "example" {
  name = "Microsoft.Network"

  feature {
    name =     "AFWEnableNetworkRuleNameLogging"
    registered = true
}
}
```

**Step2:**
Run bellow commands
**`terraform plan`**

[image]

Run below command

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

**NOTE:**

if error saying its "already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State." then please **run below command to import the respective service via terraform**

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_provider_registration.example /subscriptions/************************/providers/Microsoft.Network
```

Output as follows:

[image]

Step3:
run below commands

```
terraform plan 
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply.But can't we automate this import too.I would like to avoid this manual interruption too.

Comment: Hi Katey, When we run the Terraform plan command, it will import all the respective providers into the project code base. This respective provider, "Microsoft.Network," already existed at that time. The only option is to manually import the provider into the Terraform state file, re-run the plan, and apply. This "skip_provider_registration" is used to allow access to the API's supported providers, not all.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you , Also could you suggest that how we can avoid automatic registration of resource provider namespace  via terraform.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid manual effort of doing terroform import (using cli)

Comment: Hi Katey, there is no other way for this.  Any resource already exists, if it needs to be managed via Terraform then that resource needs to be imported into the State manually.  Apologize for late reply.

Comment: But using datablocks we can use a existing feature and update the State file right,which means we can do data block alternative to the import command.